# Como atualizar os dados de um cadastro Laravel 5.2?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.2

Estou mexendo no `Laravel` a pouco tempo, eu tenho nome, e-mail e senha e queria saber como faço para atualizar esses dados com um formulário.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading"><h4>{{ Auth::user()->name }}</h4> </div>

                <div class="panel-body">
                    <form>
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Editar Nome</label>
                         <input id="name" type="text" class="form-control" name="name" value="">
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Novo E-mail</label>
                        <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control" name="email" value="">
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Nova Senha</label>
                        <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control" name="password">
                      </div>                     
                      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Atualizar dados</button>
                       <a href="{{ url('/home') }}"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Voltar</button></a>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;


use App\Http\Requests;

class ProfileController extends Controller
{
    public function editar()
    {
        return view('editar');
    }
}
```

eu consigo cadastrar um usuário, fazer login, mas estou em duvidas de como fazer essa parte de atualizar os dados da pessoa.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public function update($id)
{
    $profile = Profile::find($id);
    $profile->update(Input::all());
    return view('suaView');
}
```

Lembrando de ter os campos $fillable cadastrados no model para o Mass Assignment funcionar direito e de forma segura.

Também deve adicionar a rota adequada, por exemplo:

```
Route::post('profile/{id}', 'ProfilesController@update');
```

Espero ter ajudado.